# bitcoind calls walletnotify before it's ready to process API calls

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I have a walletnotify configured with bitcoind.

When I start bitcoind this scipt is being called which in turn does bitcoind requests.

However, in the startup phase, bitcoind calls the walletnotify script too early, before is is actually ready to process regular RPC API requests.

In response to the request, bitcoind delivers  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.

bitcoind version: bitcoin-0.11.0 linux-32

Help appreciated, or someone does a fix in bitcoind engine?